# How do I install an Intel SSD 530 series in my desktop PC?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, motherboard

I recently bought an Intel SSD 530 series.

I have watched many tutorials and read the manual, but I'm not able to find a slot for the SSD and I also can't find where to plug in the cables. All I know is that the motherboard is "Gigabyte" and my case is Corsair obsidian something.

How do I install an Intel SSD 530 series in my desktop PC?

Comment: If you provide screenshots on a publicly hosted site (imgur.com, etc.) and give us the links we can edit them in for you.

Comment: http://www.buildcomputers.net/images/motherboard-sata-connectors.jpg SATA ports

Answer (score 1):

As-is your question is a little hard to follow, but I think I get it.

Your SSD is a 2.5" drive (laptop sized), your desktop chassis proably only has 5.25" and 3.5" bays.  ususally your HDD would be a 3.5".

If you need to put a 2.5" drive into a 3.5" bay, you'll need an adapter bracket.  Something like [this](http://ca.startech.com/HDD/Brackets/25in-Hard-Drive-to-35in-Drive-Bay-Mounting-Kit~BRACKET25SAT):

[image]

If you bought a "retail" SSD package then there's a good change it included one.  Otherwise, you can obtain them pretty easily.

As for where you plug in the cables, I'm not exactly sure which cables you mean.  You'll need to attach a SATA drive cable and a SATA power cable to the drive.

The data cable runs form the back of the drive to a SATA port on your motherboard.  They are unique (compare to other cables) and are keyed to only fit on way.

[image]

Which port to use on the motherboard for the data cable is generally up to you, but consult your motherboard's manual to learn which ports are which.

If you need to identify your motherboard (to locate the manual) open the chassis and read the model number off it.  Or if the system boots, check the BIOS, or use a software package like CPU-Z to retrieve the model number.

Comment: That pretty much answered my question, but there is one thing, the power cable is really short. How do I get it from one of the hdd cages to tje power supply

Comment: Get a power supply with leads that are the appropriate length for the size of your chassis.  Or get an appropriate extension cable (less desirable): [SATA power extension](http://www.amazon.ca/Startech-Com-12-Inch-Extension-Extender-SATAPOWEXT12/dp/B008ZB50SS)

Comment: I've got nearly everything connected to everything but I just can't find the plug in the power supply

Comment: I have a Corsair CX500M if that helps

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't find them.  Are your eyes open?  Are the lights on in the room?  Does your power supply have SATA power connectors on it?  ;)  The power supply you've mentioned is modular, meaning the cables can be detached. You need to dig up one of the SATA power cables that came with the power supply and use it.  If you can't find one, contact Corsair about buying a replacement cable.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up just to be sure and your SSD530 is SATA so simply plug in the SATA cable from the drive to your motherboard, then power do the same.. from your power supply to the drive. What you may be having trouble with for mounting is that SSDs come as 2.5" drives and your case may be too wide.  You can purchase a 2.5 to 3.5 adapter to make it fit better.  If you need more details about the hookup than that please ask and I will go into more detail.

Comment: Basically what Techie said. He just beat me to it. :)